# Merge unclosed quotations in txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a large text file. How can I check for unclosed quotations on each line and merge the lines after so the quotations start and end on the same line.

How I am getting the line with unclosed quotations

```
with open(filename, 'r') as reader:
    for index, line in enumerate(reader):
        if(line.count("\"") == 1):
            print(index, line, end='')
```

example:

```
this is my string "item 1, item 2,
item 3, item 4"
this is another string
multiple lines "test 1
test 2
test 3 "
```

I want it to look like

```
this is my string "item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4"
this is another string
multiple lines "test 1 test 2 test 3 "
```

Comment: What if there are 2 quotes on the same line and an unclosed quote on the previous line?

Comment: If there are 2 quotes on the same line then that means the quote was started and closed correctly so it should just ignore it. The way the file is structured, there should never be a quote within a quote.

Answer (score 0):

Using *your* logic to check for unclosed quotes and a `Boolean` variable:

```
with open("file", "r") as reader:
    final_str = ""
    line_continue = False
    for index, line in enumerate(reader):
        if line.count('"') % 2 == 1:
            final_str += line if line_continue else line.strip("\n") + " "
            line_continue = not line_continue
        else:
            final_str += line.strip("\n") + " " if line_continue else line
    print(final_str)
```

Prints:

```
this is my string "item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4"
this is another string
multiple lines "test 1 test 2 test 3 "
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this much, but I think it works.

```py
formatted_text = "" # output text variable
inside_quote = False # True if inside quotation marks

with open(filename) as f:
    raw_text = f.read()

for char in raw_text:
    if char == '"':
        inside_quote = not inside_quote # Inverts inside_quote
    elif char == "\n" and inside_quote:
        char = " " # Replaces newline with space if inside_quote
    formatted_text += char

print(formatted_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can read the whole file in memory, regex might be your best bet:

```
with open("/tmp/x.txt") as f:
    text = f.read()

import re

new_text = re.sub(r'"[\s\S]*?"',
        lambda x: x.group().replace("\n", " "),
        text)

print(new_text)
# this is my string "item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4"
# this is another string
# multiple lines "test 1 test 2 test 3 "
```

What's happening is we are reading the whole text file as a string, then looking for any character between `"` characters.  The `[\s\S]` includes newlines in the search.  The `?` character makes the search non-greedy so you don't just grab everything between the first and last quotation mark.

The `lambda` is a substitution function.  You are taking whatever matched the regex and replacing a newline with a space.